# Quartz providing regex in GroupMatcher

Tags: java, regex, quartz-scheduler

I am implementing a scheduler based on Quartz and have a use case where I have the start and end of a group..

Can I use GroupMatcher.jobGroupContains(someregexp) ?

I tried using it straight away, but it did not work. Is there a way something like this could work?

One possible solution is to use startsWith and endsWith to get result sets and then do an intersection, but that doesn't look like a very good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

`'^(asdf).*(ghjk)$'`

This regex matches any string that begins with `asdf` and ends with `ghjk`.

Comment: I wanted something specific to Quatrz GroupMatcher, just want to know whether a regexp can provided as parameter.

Comment: @SambhavSharma, I'm terribly sorry. I don't know anything about Quartz or GroupMatcher. The best I can help you with is `regex`. :(

Comment: Actually I knew how to write regexp for that. Thank you though, as the question had regex tag, your answer is still valid. :)